# Finding difference between populations from 1990 to 2010 and writing info to new field using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, cursor

I am trying to write a script that finds difference but every time I use the information from instructor, I am getting an error, and getting nowhere...

table:  field one is: Area_name, field two is 1990 POP, field 3 is pope 2000, and field four is pop 2010...

using ArcCatalog, I created a database located at C:/EsriPress/Script_4/US_County.gbd

broken script:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace="C:/EsriPress/Scripting_4/US_County.gbd"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = "US_County"# database
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Area_Name", "Resident_Population_1990", "Resident_Population_2010",
                                    "SHAPE@Resident_Population_2010", "SHAPE@Resident_Population_1990"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        Area_Name= row[0]
        x=row[1]
        y=row[3]
        row[4]=x
        row[5]=y
        cursor.updateRow(row)
del cursor
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you trying to create two new fields and add differences to these?

Comment: I am trying to create field and add it in

Comment: What is the full error message that you get from running the precise code that you have presented?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you want to do but you cant add new fields using the UpdateCursor, you need to use Add Field.

The shape tokens, like `SHAPE@`, or `SHAPE@XY` is for example when you need to modify geometries, or retrieve information about them. You should not need them for your problem.

I am assuming you want to add two new fields and populate with the differences of three existing fields:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace=r"C:\EsriPress\Scripting_4\US_County.gbd"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = "US_County"

fields_to_create = ["Diff_1990_2000", "Diff_2000_2010"]

for field in fields_to_create:
    arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=fc, field_name=field, field_type='DOUBLE')

input_fields = ["Pop_1990","Pop_2000","Pop_2010"] #Change to match the name of the existing fields

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, input_fields+fields_to_create) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[3] = row[1]-row[0]
        row[4] = row[2]-row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: So here is the code that I am getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/EsriPress/Scripting_4/Helped1.py", line 9, in <module>
    arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=fc, field_name=field, field_type='DOUBLE')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3443, in AddField
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset US_County does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (AddField).

Comment: Then you have an invalid path or feature class name

Comment: I am not sure why it will not refer back to the "US_Country".  It is saved in a geodatabase named US_County.gbd, which I verified.  I used ArcCatalog to make the geodatabase and import the file.  It is not open anywhere on the computer, so I am not sure what is being done wrong.

Comment: Okay.  I will try to redo the feature class

Comment: Thank you so much... I was able to get it done by redoing my geodatabase.